# Extract data with the value one in it

Tags: php, sql

i have a sql table like so

```
user_id|  Year | Math |English| Computer | Accounting|
-------|-------|------|-------|----------|-----------|
   1       12     0       1        0            1
```

So i would only like to extract the subjects which has the value 1 in it for example i would want it to `echo` like `user 1 is in year 12 and takes English and Accounting`

how can i do that i am completely lost

Comment: Poor table design... Have one class column and several rows, not several columns and and one row. (Perhaps another table is needed.)

Answer (score -1):

You can try a simple query such as:

```
select * from `TABLE` where `math`=1 or `english`=1 or `computer`=1 or `accounting`=1;
```

replace `TABLE` with the actual table name though!

Comment: This will still select all the columns.